# The My Logins page does not adapt well when the browser window is too narrow

Tags: bug, feature-request, user-interface

I wanted to change my stackoverflow password. I searched in the "Edit profile and settings" tab, but could not find it. I have eventually figured out that it is on the "My Logins" sub-tab
`https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/<useridhere>` and successfully changed it. The problem was: I could not see the "change password" link because my browser window was too narrow and it was off-screen.

Comment: The user page is currently in the process of being redesigned, I hope. Issues like these are already known.